# ファイル操作の監視方法について(.NetFramework)

Tags: c#, .net

Windows10の全ドライブ全域からログオンユーザーがファイル操作した(開く、保存、コピー、削除など)ログをデータベースで記録を残すことを目的としたファイル監視プログラムを作成するために以下の方法でファイル操作を検知しようとしております。

ETW(イベントトレーシング):
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/event-tracing-for-windows--etw-

ETWから検知したイベントを組み合わせてファイルの状態(開く、閉じる、コピー、削除など)を判定しようとしていますが、以下が課題点となっております。

- Office関連のファイル(word excel powerpointなど)の保存やコピーを検知できない。
- 新規ファイル生成のみの判定方法が不明。
- 新規ファイルのコピーが検知できない。

FileSystemWatcherを使った方法も検討しましたがシステム全域の監視ができないためETWを選択しました。
これらの課題点を解決できる方法をご存じでしたらご教授いただければ幸いです。
また、これまでETWをあまり使ったこともなかったため、ETWの詳細な情報が掲載されているサイトがございましたら教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 監視するなら、監査ポリシーを利用するのが適当と思います。監視して独自のプログラムを作ってまで何をしたいのか、まで説明されると良いのでは。

Comment: @htb様
コメントありがとうございます。監査ポリシーに関して利用できるか確認したいため、詳しい情報が記載されているサイト等ご存じないでしょうか？